# Chart only prints out first value using jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chart.js

Im trying to print out the Gender distribution from student records to `Chart.js` but it only prints first data into the chart

[image]

What I am basically doing is that I am trying to count all instances of `studGender` as total from `stud_orgmember` and grouping it by `studGender(Female, Male)`.

and i can't seem to make it work here is the code for **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Creating Dynamic Data Graph using PHP and Chart.js</title>
<style type="text/css">
BODY {
    width: 550PX;
}

#chart-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart-container">
        <canvas id="graphCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showGraph();
        });


        function showGraph()
        {
            {
                $.post("data.php",
                function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                     var name = [];
                    var marks = [];


            for(var i in data){
            name.push(data[i].studGender);
                        marks.push(data[i].total);
            }

                    var chartdata = {
                        labels: name,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Gender Distribution from SOs',
                                backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                                borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                                hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                                hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                                data: marks
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                    var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");

                    var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: chartdata
                    });
                });
         }
         }
        </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Here is the subsequent code for **data.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","soumis");

$sqlQuery = "SELECT studGender, COUNT(studGender) AS total FROM stud_orgmember GROUP BY studGender";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess that the value of male is `27`. In which case, looking at the y-axis reveals the problem:

[image]

What you probably need to do is set `beginAtZero: true`:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marco Did this answer your question?